# Getting error on ADFS login with one login saml plugin

Tags: wordpress, single-sign-on, saml, adfs

We are using wordpress one login saml plugin. All of a sudden the adfs login stopped working. On checking adfs logs it is throwing below error:

MICROSOFT.IDENTITYSERVER.SERVICE.SECURITYTOKENSERVICE.REVOCATIONVALIDATIONEXCEPTION

We checked service provider certificate is valid and not expired or revoked. We are clueless what could be the issue and at which end is it ons ervice provider end or idp end and how to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

The best place to look for this is in the ADFS event log.

It could be the ADFS token signing certificate or the ADFS encryption certificate or the SAML certificate that you uploaded from the SAML RP.

Or it could be that your certificate has failed on the certificate revocation list.